# symfony 5.2 unrecognized option 'http_version' under framework.http_client

Tags: symfony

I'm trying to implement async HTTP client with Symfony and [amphp/http-client](https://amphp.org/http-client/), in [symfony docs](https://symfony.com/doc/current/http_client.html#http-2-support) said thatto enable it for HTTP I need to add `http_version: '2.0'`option to config and I did it:

```
framework:
    http_client:
        http_version: '2.0'
        scoped_clients:
            site:
                base_uri: '%env(URL)%'
                headers:
                    x-access-token: '%env(ACCESS_TOKEN)%'
```

but it's not working and I'm getting error   `Unrecognized option "http_version" under "framework.http_client". Available options are "default_options", "enabled", "max_host_connections", "mock_response_factory", "scoped_clients".`

Any idea what is wrong?? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the docs might need to be updated a bit.  Under a 5.2 app:

```
bin/console config:dump-reference framework http_client

# HTTP Client configuration
http_client:
    enabled:              true

    # The maximum number of connections to a single host.
    max_host_connections: ~
    default_options:

        # Associative array: header => value(s).
        headers:

            # Prototype
            name:                 ~

        # The maximum number of redirects to follow.
        max_redirects:        ~

        # The default HTTP version, typically 1.1 or 2.0, leave to null for the best version.
        http_version:         ~
```

So http_version goes under default_options

```
# config/packages/framework.yaml
framework:
    http_client:
        default_options:
            http_version: '2.0'

bin/console debug:config framework http_client

Current configuration for "framework.http_client"
=================================================

default_options:
    http_version: '2.0'
    headers: {  }
    resolve: {  }
    retry_failed:
        enabled: false
        retry_strategy: null
        http_codes: {  }
        max_retries: 3
        delay: 1000
        multiplier: 2
        max_delay: 0
        jitter: 0.1
enabled: true
scoped_clients: {  }
```